# Firebase Storage memory leak when downloading a number of photos from downloadURLs on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage

I uploaded some photos to Firebase Storage following the [sample project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/storage/StorageExampleSwift/) on github.

Before using Firebase Storage, I was saving my photos to some other website. And when I download photos from those image URLs that I saved before on the other website, nothing is wrong and memory usage is reasonable. But when I paste images' URL links to corresponding childs on Firebase Database and then download from those URLs, I seem to have a terrible memory issue. For every ~200kb image, memory usage goes ~10mb up. Since I don't have this problem downloading images from other URLs, I believe this is a firebase specific issue. Does anyone else encounter the same memory issue? Any suggestions/help?

**NOTE:** I saved the URLs of the images to the firebase realtime database. I download URL links from there and give them to my photo collection view cells. Here is the code I wrote for my photo collection view cells:

```
class PhotosCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

  private var downloadTask: FIRStorageDownloadTask!

  var imageURL: String! {
    didSet {
      downloadTask = FIRStorage.storage().referenceForURL(imageURL).dataWithMaxSize(1*1024*1024) { (imageData, error) in
      guard error == nil else { print(error); return }
      if let imageData = imageData {
      self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
      }
//      imageView.kf_showIndicatorWhenLoading = true
//      imageView.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageURL)!)
      }
    }
  }

  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    imageView.image = nil
    //    imageView.kf_cancelDownloadTask()
    downloadTask.cancel()
  }
}
```

The only thing I want to solve is that I want to be able to download the images that I saved to Firebase Storage from their URLs that I also save in the real time database. One important fact is that kingfisher downloads images from URLs without having any memory issue. The problem just occurs when those image URLs are from firebase storage.

**NOTE:** I also get memory issue when download those images from Firebase Storage function. I know to some extent it's normal for memory usage to go up but my images in Firebase Storage are just about 200KB.

Comment: Can you post some code as to how you're downloading those URLs? Are you just using the sample project and noticing it there?

Comment: Thanks for answering Frank. No, I don't want to store photos on local disk so I use(and have been using without any memory problem) a popular third party [library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to download images.

Comment: Could that be because iOS is not so much good at decompressing jpeg images compared to png type? And is it possible to save images in png format to Firebase Storage? I tried to change metadata such that ` metadata.contentType = "image/png"` but when I download after uploading with this metadata, I see that the image format is still JPEG.

Comment: If you're not using the built in download features from Firebase Storage, you're simply passing a download URL to some third party library, it doesn't sound like this is an issue with Firebase Storage--it sounds like the third party library is having trouble with the download.

Comment: Also, changing the content type without changing the actual encoding of the file doesn't do anything--you need to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Comment: I am afraid I encounter a serious memory issue with Firebase Storage. The problem is, I have _already_ been using the image downloader library for urls stored somewhere else and I've never faced memory issue when downloading images from urls. So the only difference is that image url links are from Firebase Storage. So that has to be the root of the problem. Is my thinking wrong somewhere? And also, I've just tried the Firebase method _dataWithMaxSize_ to see if it will solve the issue. But this also **does not** solve the memory issue when downloading the images I uploaded to Firebase Storage.

Comment: Post code with a repro: two URLs being downloaded (one with, one without the memory issue) so I can test this out. Without this, chatting about it won't move the conversation forward. Also--`dataWithMaxSize` will pull everything into memory, so I totally expect that this will use up a bunch of memory (though 200kB -> 10MB seems a little extreme).

Comment: Chat invitation was mistakenly clicked Mike, sorry for that. I've just edited  my question and shared the code. Is my problem clear now? Or do you need a fully functioning example repo that produces the memory issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While you are only downloading 200kb blobs of data, it costs much more memory than that to display that as an image. While the "clarity" of the image may be compressed, it will still remain the same dimensions. An image usually requires 4 bytes per pixel - one for each of red, blue, green, and alpha. So a 2000x1000 pixel image requires ~8mb of memory, which is close to what you are describing. I would first ask you if you are caching the *images*, and if you are, instead cache the *data*. What will probably help you more though is to resize the image that you are displaying, unless you need it at full size. Use something like:

```
extension UIImage {

    /// Returns a image that fills in newSize
    func resizedImage(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        // Guard newSize is different
        guard self.size != newSize else { return self }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

And do something like half of the dimensions of the original image, which will make it cost 4x less memory. Make sure to modify the original image and not to create a new image. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem, and one thing which helped me it is SDWebImage. It can load images from refs and direct url.